# Elasticsearch Percolator index + Dynamic index templates

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm creating a dynamic index mapping template like this.

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to add a percolator field as part of this template something like below (it does not work):

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "query": {
      "type": "percolator"
    },
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I create a dynamic mapping template with a percolator support?

**[Update]**
I created a dynamic mapping like this and the below works:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "query": {
        "type": "percolator"
      }
    },
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But when I ingest a document like this:

```
PUT /my-index-000001/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "action": {
    "webhook": {
      "tenantId": "tenantA"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "message: bonsai"
    }
  }
}
```

It fails with the error below:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "query_shard_exception",
        "reason": "No field mapping can be found for the field with name [message]",
        "index_uuid": "R6UGg60fQW-lPmHPXrhxBQ",
        "index": "my-index-000001"
      }
    ],
    "type": "document_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[11:3] failed to parse: No field mapping can be found for the field with name [message]",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "query_shard_exception",
      "reason": "No field mapping can be found for the field with name [message]",
      "index_uuid": "R6UGg60fQW-lPmHPXrhxBQ",
      "index": "my-index-000001"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Does it expect a field to be physically present in the mapping when specified in the query string query?

Answer (score 0):

Good job so far! You're almost there, you simply need to do it like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {                  <----- add this section
      "query": {
        "type": "percolator"
      }
    },
    "dynamic_templates": [
      {
        "strings": {
          "match_mapping_type": "string",
          "mapping": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I have a different issue when I insert the document in the index. Updated my question above.

Comment: That's because all the fields used in your query (even in query_string) need to be declared in your mapping and you're missing the `message` field

Comment: Ok, but in my case, I don't want to define the mapping upfront. That's why I use dynamic templates to infer the mapping based on the ingested document. I'd have thought that's what the dynamic mapping is intended for? Right?

Comment: Yes, but the constraint for the percolator type is that all fields you use in your queries are pre-defined, otherwise the percolator cannot do its job.